# Formatting MySQL datetime with PHP

Tags: php

I am using PHP 5.3.18.

What would be the best way to convert the following two variables to the following 5 output formats? Note that $date is derived from standard MySQL datetime and date columns, however, I don't wish to use MySQL to format them.

```
$date='2013-12-25 10:51:54'
$date='2013-12-25'

12/25/2013
Week 52 of year 2013
Month 12 of year 2013
Quarter 4 of year 2013
2013
```

I can use either of the following two solutions, but don't know if one is better than the other, or whether a better solution exists.

```
echo(date("m/d/Y", strtotime($date)));

$dtime = new DateTime($date);
echo($dtime->format("m/d/Y"));
```

Thanks

EDIT - This is what I ended up doing.

```
$value=$date->format("m/d/Y");break;   // 12/25/2013
$value='Week '.$date->format("w").' of year '.$date->format("Y");break;   // Week 52 of year 2013
$value=$date->format("F").' '.$date->format("Y");break;   // December 2013
$value='Quarter '.ceil($date->format("n")/3).' of year '.$date->format("Y");break;   // Quarter 4 of year 2013
$value=$date->format("Y");break;   // 2013
```

Comment: `DateTime` has a way nicer API *and* it will keep on working after 2038.

Comment: Since you are using PHP 5.3, I would recommened using second one

Comment: Well you are already of to the right start with looking at the `DateTime` object. Really the task is easy once you have that part figured out.  Just use repeated calls with different values passed to `format()`

Comment: Sounds like DataTime is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just in this case better (considering performance) would be using date function.

Sometimes you need more complicated operations - and then DateTime class may be better (more handy and readable code for sure).

That would be all I think.

Comment: Thanks MFix.  I probably should have done a better job defining "better"

Comment: To be honest the performance is still the only thing that comes to my mind while thinking about "better" :) Still, I hope it's somehow useful for you.